# How users could use registry Governance (GREG) to search for available services?

Tags: wso2

We needed to provide a tool where our customers (people) could search for published services. We're trying to use the Governance Registry but do not know the correct way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is by using the java API provided by WSO2. With this API you can browse and search through the registry.

```
    Resource governanceFolder = registry.get("/_system/governance");
    System.out.println("Folder description: " +                         
                         governanceFolder.getDescription());            

    // get the WSDL folder resource (use the url we browsed to)   
    String wsdlUrl = "/_system/governance/trunk/wsdls/_0/service_1" +
            "/account/wsdl/trafficavoidance/accountService.wsdl";
    Resource wsdlResource = registry.get(wsdlUrl);

    // output the content of the wsdl
    System.out.println(new String((byte[])wsdlResource          
                                          .getContent()));

    List<Resource> paths = getServicePath(registry, "/_system/governance/trunk/services");
```

Configuring and setting up the client is a bit difficult. I've written a blog post on this a couple of weeks ago. So if you need more info you could look there: http://www.smartjava.org/content/access-wso2-registry-programatically

Answer (score 0):

Following links might help you
-[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/CRUD+operation+support+for+Configurable+Governance+Artifacts
-[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Configurable+Governance+Artifacts+with+API

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.